# How to edit proreties of activity

Tags: android, properties, android-activity

I work with ADT Bundle. I have 4 activities in my project. activity_main is main activity and was created when project was created. After I created other activities with File -> New -> Other. In this wizard I has chechbox "Lauuncher Activity". I selected it. After I understood that this checkbox shows your activities in main menu of device. How can I unselect this?

`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Bu oyun adamlarda hasaplamalary gechirmani owretmek uchin duzulendir!!!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="Habarlashmak uchin: +99365814342" />
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your AndroidManifest.xml, go to the XML view and then remove the following `intent-filter` from the Activities you don't want in the launcher:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```